# How to clean up Miniprofiler old data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I have a asp.net core web api 3.1 application . I have added Miniprofiler nuget package (mentioned below) to profile the web apis in order to understand the performance issues.

```
Install-Package MiniProfiler.AspNetCore
```

Install-Package MiniProfiler.EntityFrameworkCore

I am able to successfully build the application and open the Miniprofiler url: https://localhost:44348/profiler/results-index , I see a page with profiler results.

I do see old data displayed in the profiler results. How to clean up the old data in this case or how can we start a new profile result session each time we run the project ?